# difference between 'function to class' vs 'class to class' for gtest codegen?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, googletest

'function to class' generates unit test code of class for each function in target code,while 'class to class' genertes unit test code of class for each class in target code.
I just wonder what's the difference? and when to use them separately in real world?

Comment: Can you point me to the particular code generator that you're using? I cannot find any code generators for Google C++ Testing Framework.